# Changing Bounding Box Dimensions

Tags: matlab

New to Matlab here. I'm trying to implement some code to detect a face in an image and crop it. I have the script running, but the bounding box that it places around the detected face is a bit small. Is there any way to change the dimensions of the bounding box to capture more of the faces?

```
clc;
% cd into the a folder with pictures
cd 'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\folder'

files = dir('*.jpg');

for file = files'  
img = imread(file.name); 
figure(1),imshow(img); 
FaceDetect = vision.CascadeObjectDetector; 
FaceDetect.MergeThreshold = 7; 
BB = step(FaceDetect,img); 
figure(2),imshow(img); 
for i = 1:size(BB,1)
    rectangle('Position',BB(i,:),'LineWidth',2,'LineStyle','- ','EdgeColor','r'); 
end

for i = 1:size(BB,1)
    rectangle('Position',BB(i,:),'LineWidth',2,'LineStyle','- ','EdgeColor','r');
    J = imcrop(img,BB(i,:));
    figure(3);
    imshow(J);
    a = 'edited\'
    b = file.name
    output = strcat(a,b);
    imwrite(J,output);
end

%Code End
end
```

Currently, the script finds a face like so:
[image]

And outputs an image such as this:
[image]

This is good, I just want to extend the boundaries of the cropping zone to capture more of the face (e.g., hair and chin).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the MATLAB rectangle function documentation.

- rectangle('Position',pos) creates a rectangle in 2-D coordinates.
  Specify pos as a four-element vector of the form [x y w h] in data
  units. The x and y elements determine the location and the w and h
  elements determine the size. The function plots into the current axes
  without clearing existing content from the axes.

If you are just looking to increase the bounding box by some scale factor about the center of the rectangle, you could scale the `w` and `h` components in `BB` and adjust the rectangle origin `x` and `y` by subtracting half the scale difference. The following code should work if you place it right after the `BB = step(FaceDetect,img);` line in your code. I don't have MATLAB available to me at the moment but I'm pretty sure this will work.

```
% Scale the rectangle to 1.2 times its original size
scale = 1.2;

% Adjust the lower left corner of the rectangles
BB(:,1:2) = BB(:,1:2) - BB(:,3:4)*0.5*(scale - 1)

% Adjust the width and height of the rectangles
BB(:,3:4) = BB(:,3:4)*scale;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use imresize function in Matlab as described in this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imresize.html#mw_7f1dd55c-032d-4e1a-bb52-dcaae33f3855) and [bboxresize](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/bboxresize.html) to resize the bounding box
Below is the simple code to resize your image into 3 times the original one

```
%% clean workspace
clc;
clear;
cd 'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\folder';
files = dir('*.jpg');
for file = files'
 img = imread(file.name) ;
 figure(1),imshow(img);
 FaceDetect = vision.CascadeObjectDetector;
 FaceDetect.MergeThreshold =7;
 BB = step(FaceDetect,img);
 BB2 = BB;
 %% Scale the rectangle to 3 times its original size
 scale = 3;
 %% Resize image
 ImgResized = imresize(img,scale);
 %% Resize bound box using the function named bboxresize in Matlab
 BBResized = bboxresize(BB,scale);
 figure(2),imshow(ImgResized);
 %% Draw Bounding Box
  for i=1:size(BBResized,1)
    rectangle('position',BBResized(i,:),'lineWidth',2,'LineStyle','- ','EdgeColor','y');
   end
end
```